# Recreating distribution certs in enterprise apps

Tags: developer-program, certificate, enterprise

I have an enterprise account and the distribution certificate for the account is going to expire. I read through the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW29) and understand that I need to generate a new certificate and attach that to the existing mobileprovision.

My question is, once I do that, will I need to recreate an ipa (with this updated mobileprovision) for users having the existing app and will these users need to re-download it? Or will the existing enterprise distribution still work without any changes?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems more appropriate to live on Stack Overflow.

Comment: SO is only for programming questions, this is not really a programming question and might be kicked off of there.

Comment: Per the SO help page tools that developers use are fair game to ask about. You can leave it here, but you might get more views on SO.

Comment: I'd be happy to move this over to SO if any of the moderators think it doesn't belong here. Thanks...

Comment: I have an app in the App Store for like 4 or 5 years now and I think I haven't created a new cert for this app, but this could be different to enterprise apps...